# Deploy Sandbox to production: Cannot specify a startsWith attribute for this language

Tags: sandbox, eclipse, production, deployment, force.com-ide

I'm trying to migrate some changes to the org org sandbox to production. Use the Eclipse IDE to develop, however, when I try to migrate a custom object in the "deploy to server" option get the following message.

> Cannot specify a startsWith attribute for this language

The language in both org's is the same as the entire configuration.
Could you help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<startsWith>Vowel</startsWith>` from the custom object xml and then try to deploy.  If deployment is successful you can log into your production org and update the value from the custom object configuration page.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error but during a scratch org creation. Maybe someone will find it helpful: to fix the problem, add the language parameter to your project-scratch-def file:

```
    {
    ...
  "language": "en_US",
    ...
    }
```